# Webservice call with unique ID when Amazon Elastic Transcoder finishes a job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, video-encoding, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I wanted to know if there is an option to trigger a URL call per specific video Id when Amazon Elastic transcoder finishes a transcoding job.

Right now, I can create an SNS topic and assign it to the "*On Completion Event*". This SNS topic can be a call to a specific URL for example.

My problem is that I can't figure out the proper way to implement it in code (**using AWS SDK for .NET**) to call a page with a query string and unique ID that will tell the server which specific video that was transcoded is ready.

**My current solution that I was thinking to implement:**
What I was thinking is to create a unique pipepline and unique SNS topic for each video that is uploaded.

Is there a better way to implement this. Again, I need to know when a specific video is finished the encoding process and ready to be downloaded. If I have a unique id attached to the SNS topic URL call, I will be able to know if that video is ready. However, creating a lot of SNS topics and piplines seems a weird way to do this, and I am searching a better way to do it.

Another option that I was thinking and I don't know if it's possible, is to create the pipline without any notifications (I know that they are optional), but when I run a job via a specific pipline, then to assign a new SNS topic for the "On Completion" event.

Answer (score 0):

When a transcoding job is created, a job id is returned. Then when the SNS completion notification is fired, the sent message contains that specific job id so you can know which transcoding job has finished.

What we do is save into DB the job id along with the media id that is being transcoded, and then when we receive the SNS notification, we query the DB to know which media corresponds to the received transcoder job id.

For more information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/notifications.html